# Style a styled-components within a wrapper

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I would like to add an animation and a specific height to a Button that is styled. The thing is, my `StyledButton` is a wrapper that can render one of multiple pre-styled buttons according to a `type` prop which are styled [React Semantic UI Buttons](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/button/).

See the CodeSandbox with reproduction here :

https://codesandbox.io/embed/practical-haibt-oz9sl

The thing is it does get the styles from the `ActionButton` but it does not apply whatever style I put on the `const AnimatedButton = styled(StyledButton)`.

But, if I try the same thing without the wrapper, directly by importing the `BaseButton`, and creating a `AnimatedBaseButton`, this one works but 
removes the modularity of having a `type` prop that returns a pre-styled button.

I searched here and on google / github, but there's no issue that reflects this one. I know I could add an `animation` property on the `StyledButton` and pass it, but with the real codebase, it's not possible.

Thanks in advance !

EDIT : Added a Codesandbox instead of code example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Quick fix:

In `StyledButton.js`:

```
render() {
  const {
    content,
    icon,
    iconPosition,
    onClick,
    type,
    ...otherProps // take base props passed through wrapper
  } = this.props;

  // ...

  return (
    <ButtonToDisplay
      {...otherProps} // spread it firstly here so below props can override
      onClick={onClick}
      content={content}
    />
  );
}
```

## Why it works:

As you can see, `styled(comp)''` syntax we use to style our component is actually a HOC component under the hood, which takes in a component and returns another component.

So when you make a wrapper that intercepts between a `styled component` and the `real component`, you need to allow `props` that generated by the library go through that wrapper.

Comment: Thanks @DatLe , it was exactly that !! Didn't know we had to pass the props, but it seems logical as it passes the `className` prop !!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `...` (spread operator) while destructing `this.props`

```
export default class StyledButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    //     added ... (spread operator) 
    const {type, ...additionalProps} = this.props
    if (type === 'normal') return <NormalButton {...aditionalProps} />
    else if (type === 'action') return <ActionButton {...aditionalProps} />
  }
}
```

What is happening here is that `styled-component` pass the styles in the `style` prop, but with out the spread operator, you aren't passing it, you are just getting a prop that is called `additionalProps`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out ! Following your comment, I decided to take time to create a Codesandbox to avoid code formatting issues with the stackoverflow editor.